# Apache Spark cannot start due to a NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, apache-spark, slf4j

I have brew installed apache-spark 1.6.1 on OSX El Capitan. Upon spark-shell, I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory.newForField(MutableMetricsFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsSourceBuilder.add(MetricsSourceBuilder.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsSourceBuilder.<init>(MetricsSourceBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsAnnotations.newSourceBuilder(MetricsAnnotations.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.MetricsSystem.register(MetricsSystem.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:224)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2160)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2160)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2160)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.<init>(SparkIMain.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter.<init>(SparkILoop.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createInterpreter(SparkILoop.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:949)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
14:17:50.398 [Thread-0] INFO  o.a.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager - Shutdown hook called
14:17:50.401 [Thread-0] INFO  o.a.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager - Deleting directory /private/var/folders/pc/wx3xk3sx7_35n6v1qj9knv9c0000gq/T/spark-0a979df4-f61f-4805-a942-8e62350331db
```

I installed Jave SE already, and I suspect this same problem is preventing my pyspark (with a similar error).

Comment: It looks like the problem may be in the way the logging framework is set up.  Try looking at https://bradleyaross.wordpress.com/2016/05/05/java-logging-frameworks/.  Are you getting other messages in your log file.

Comment: I would recommend that you install park directly from a binary file instead of brew.